# Is there a better way to do it? I want to literally subtract characters from one array into another

Tags: java, arrays, time-complexity

So what i am basically trying to do here is to take out the characters such as 'S' 'P' 'O' 'R' 'T' from the array which contains all the alphabets from 'A'...'Z'  This code works fine but i want to know if there is a better way to do it.. a more simplified version or so..  And i would appreciate answers which involves only arrays n not list or hashes!

```
String key = "SPORT";
char [] keys = key.toCharArray();

String alphabets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
char [] alpha = alphabets.toCharArray();
int len = alpha.length;
int keylen = keys.length;
System.out.println(len);
int new_len = (alpha.length) - keylen;
char [] newalpha = new char [new_len];
for (int j = 0 ; j < keys.length ; j++) {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++) {
        if (alpha[i] == keys[j]) {
            alpha[i] = '@';
        }
    }
}
int k = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < len ; i++) {
    if (alpha[i] != '@') {
        newalpha[k] = alpha[i];
        k++;
    }
}
for (int i = 0 ; i < newalpha.length ; i++) {
    System.out.println(newalpha[i]);
}
```

Comment: you just went through this to take out these  'S' 'P' 'O' 'R' 'T'?!!!! what is keylen? you never define such a variable

Comment: "And I would appreciate answers which involves only arrays n not list or hashes!" Why not?  Lists and hashes (or especially sets) will do this for you, which makes them much easier.

Comment: @Pokechu22 wowwwwwww such a good one you indicate, and the OP is looking for something faster and more optimize lol

Comment: @KickButtowski I don't understand what you mean.  Lists and sets are optimized for this kind of thing.  You wouldn't need to deal with hashes.  What's being done here is probably not optimal.

Comment: @Pokechu22 I was just agreeing with you, and I was sarcastic. and I canot believe the op went through this just extract those letters. beside the code has issues too

Answer (score 1):

In Java 8

**Code**:

```
    String alphabets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(alphabets.split(""));

    List<String> result = list.stream().filter(s -> !(s.equals("S") || s.equals("P") || s.equals("O")
            || s.equals("R") || s.equals("T"))).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println("The list of letters after after extractison S P O R T are ");
    result.stream().forEach(s -> System.out.print(" " + s));
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("The number of letters after extractison S P O R T is " + result.stream().count());
```

**Output**:

```
The list of letters after after extractison S P O R T are 
 A B C D E F G H I J K L M N Q U V W X Y Z
The number of letters after extractison S P O R T is 21
```

**Explanation**:

As far as I know lambda in `Java 8` just works with List, so I converted the String to the list by using `Arrays.asList`. Next I used `filter` which works like `if` statement to go through the list and ignore `S P O R` and `T` and collect them as `List` named result. At the end, I print the list by using new form of `for loop` and show how many letters we have after extraction those letters.

**Cleaned up Version**:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;


public class TakeOutChars {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String alphabets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(alphabets.split(""));
    System.out.println(filterSPORT(list, ignoreSPORT()));
    System.out.println(filterSPORT(list, ignoreSPORT()).stream().count());
}

public static Predicate ignoreSPORT() {
return s -> !(s.equals("S") || s.equals("P") || s.equals("O")
            || s.equals("R") || s.equals("T"));

  }

public static List<String> filterSPORT(List list, Predicate predicate) {
    return (List<String>) list.stream().filter( predicate ).collect(Collectors.toList());
}   
  }
```

**Output of Cleaned up Version**:

```
[A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, Q, U, V, W, X, Y, Z]
21
```

Comment: that is one hell of an answer deserve +1

Comment: @KickButtowski Nice! You can improve the readability by changing your predicate to `s -> !"SPORT".contains(s);`

Comment: @matsev thank your for your input. can you explain it more to me? thank you :) –  Kick Buttowski 22 mins ago

Comment: @KickButtowski Sure. Rather than having repeated `s.equals(..)` methods in the predicate function (which IMHO makes it more difficult to see which letters should be excluded), you could simply just write `List<String> result = list.stream().filter(s -> !("SPORT".contains(s))).collect(Collectors.toList());`. Alternatively, `public static Predicate ignoreSPORT() {return s -> !("SPORT".contains(s));}`, see the JavaDoc of [String.contains()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-) for details.

Comment: @matsev I do not know how to report a person who plagiarized. he just copy past answer from duplicated post. can you help me?

Comment: @KickButtowski I am not sure what is the best way to deal with it. On one hand, it could be a perfect solution to a specific question. On the other hand, one can claim that it would be fair if the original answer is at least acknowledged if the solution is copied. You'd better check at [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/) perhaps there are some general guide lines.

Comment: @matsev mr craft reported him wanna see the links?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below mentioned code:

```
String key = "SPORT";
key  = key.toUpperCase();
char[] keys = key.toCharArray();

String alphabets = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

for (char c : keys) {
    alphabets = alphabets.replace(c, '@');
}

alphabets = alphabets.replaceAll("@", "");
System.out.println(alphabets);
```